# Using a Release-Configured DLL in another project that is configured for debugging?

Tags: c++, dll

If I use a DLL built on release configuration on a project that is configured for debugging, I got weird errors. But if I switch the project to release mode, the program runs smoothly. Do I really have to use the debug DLL for debugging? Keeping 2 versions of DLL can be tricky. I have actually tried this scenario in C# and there are no problems. I'm new in making DLLs, so I need a little clarification.

Comment: You'll have two distinct copies of the C and C++ runtime in the process.  Not good, unless the DLL interface is carefully designed to avoid trouble.  No C++ standard template class objects, no exceptions, no memory ownership delegation.  Visual Studio strongly encourages creating a solution with both projects so they get compiled and tested with compatible options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very much dependant on the data types exposed in your DLL interface (and more specifically: do you have std container types contained in your headers?).

consider this bit of code:

```cpp
class DLL_EXPORT Foo {
public:

   std::vector<int>& getThing() {
      return m_foo;
   }

private:
   std::vector<int> m_foo;
};
```

If you compile in visual C++, you should get a few warning C4251's popping up. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4251?view=msvc-170

chances are the std::vector implementation will be littered with bits of code like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void vector<T>::resize(size_t s) {
  #ifdef _DEBUG
  resize_with_debug_allocator_and_lots_of_checks(s);
  #else
  resize_with_release_allocator(s);
  #endif
}
```

The data types themselves may also have stuff like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class vector {

private:
  #ifdef _DEBUG
  some_additional_debugging_member_vars stuff;
  #endif
  T* begin;
  T* end;
  T* capacity;
};
```

So there problem here is that your DLL depends on having the release CRT available, but your exe requires the debug CRT to be available, and since the standard types are passing across your DLL boundary, you now have problems!

It is possible to create a DLL interface that can be used in a mix of debug/release, but it's often more hassle than it's worth (unless you are say developing a plugin API for a commercial software application!).

The general rules are:

- Make sure you have zero C4251 warnings in your build!
- Do not have header files that contain boost/STL at all!
- Memory allocated by the DLL must be freed by the DLL (and vice versa).
- Any class/struct types in your DLL interface must have the same memory layout between debug/release.
- Be super careful of inline methods in your DLL headers. These should always be exported!
- By the same token, also be careful of implicitly defined functions (e.g. copy constructors / destructors etc). These need to be exported.
- Do not throw std::exception (you can throw your own exception objects, but they need to be part of your DLL header, and you need to follow the same rules as above).

Alternatively, just expose a C interface to your DLL (the same rules about memory allocation apply), but that avoids most of the nastiness with passing C++ objects across the DLL boundary.

It's usually a lot simpler to just have a debug and a release build DLL to be honest.